# separating an Eloquent Model from business logic

Tags: php, laravel, orm, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

I want to write discrete framework agnostic models.

I wrote interfaces for all of these models.

The problem is when implementing these interfaces, for example with Eloquent I'm linking all my business logic into the ORM.

For example I want a method `addVariation` on a `Product` model.

**The Interface**

```
interface ProductInterface
{   
    /**
     * Adds a variation
     *
     * @param VariationInterface $variation
     */
    public function addVariation(VariationInterface $variation);

    // ...
}
```

**The Concretion**

```
class Product extends Model 
{
    /**
     *  @param Collection | VariationInterface
     */
    protected $variations;

    public function addVariation(VarientInterface $varient)
    {
        if( ! $this->hasVariation($varient) ) 
        {
            $this->variations->add($variations);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The problem I have is all my business logic lives in my specific Eloquent ORM implementation of my model.

How could I possibly separate this out? The only real dependancy I can see is I need a collection class of some type? or maybe I can just use plain old arrays?

*I just dont want to link all my logic into a specific ORM* I want to remain framework agnostic.

Comment: You can create a repository that interfaces with eloquent, this will allow you to switch out your model but keep the same interface.  I went through a similar thing but for the size of my projects (not very big) I decided to keep things simpler.  http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories/ for more info.  actually all his blog posts are pretty good for starting out in laravel.

Comment: To be honest, I find it very hard to code framework agnostic model even though you use repository pattern. That bunch of repositories, from my understanding, are essentially interfaces which are normally injected into Laravel controllers. Yeah you seem to separate your controllers from business logic, but do not forget those Laravel controllers heavily use other Laravel components like Redirect or View.

Comment: When it comes to models, you cannot really get rid of Laravel entirely. For example, if you want to automatically reformat your data somehow before it is displayed in views, you are very likely to define some Laravel setters and getters: setXXXAttribute() and getXXXAttribute(). This feature is definitely great, but coding like this leads to dependence on Laravel, let alone they usually extend Eloquent.

Comment: In sum, for me the benefits of adopting repository / interface pattern are more about separation of concerns of Laravel-powered application, and more testable code in the context of Laravel, rather than you could build framework agnostic models. @uberweb

Answer (score 4):

Just remove all your logic from the Eloquent ORM.

You only need an ORM to make saving and retrieving data from a database easier. You should write all your business logic with plain old php objects. You can then create some general `PersistenceGateway` interface that all your business logic models use e.g.

```
interface PersistenceGatway {

   public function saveGatewayData($id, array $data);

   public function retrieveGatewayData($id)
}
```

Your decoupled business logic uses this interface to `save` and `retrieve` data. Then all you need to do is implement the interface with your ORM of choice (or you may need to also create some adaptor class to help you). You can now plugin any ORM you like, so long as it implements the `PersistenceGateway` interface.

Take a look at [Uncle Bobs Clean Architecture](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html). Web frameworks like Laravel should be a plugin to your app/business logic, not the other way around.

Edit: Very basic example.

```
class SomeBusinessLogic {

   // Note: Class depends on the PersistenceGateway. Any class
   // that implements this interface can be passed in. This is
   // essentially how you decouple logic from ORMS. You can now 
   // implement this interface with any ORM you like and pass it in
   public __construct(PersistenceGateway $gateway){
      $this->gateway = $gateway;
   } 

   public function someLogicMethod($id){
      // do something and save state to the gateway
      $this->gateway->saveGatewayData($id, ['some_state'=>'value']);
   }

   public function someDataReturnMethod($id){
      return $this->gateway->retrieveGatewayData($id);
   }

}

// Im extending from Eloquent here, but you can do a similar thing
// with any ORM.
class SomeEloquentModel extends Eloquent implements PersistenceGateway {

   public function saveGatewayData($id, array $data){
       $model = $this->find($id);
       // call eloquent save method
       $model->save($data);
   }

   public function retrieveGatewayData($id){
       // retrieve the data. Important to return
       // an array NOT an eloquent model, otherwise
       // we are still coupled. I think toArray() is
       // the correct method to call on eloquent model
       return $this->find($id)->toArray();
   }
}

class SomeController {

    class someControllerMethod {
       // Your controller decides on the implementation of PersistenGateway
       // to use. You could also use an IoC container which would be a slightly
       // cleaner solution
       $logic = new SomeBusinessLogic(new SomeEloquentModel());
       $logic->someLogicMethod(Input::get('id'));
       return $logic->someDataReturnMethod(Input::get('id'));
    }

}
```

Comment: How can I possibly do that with the active record pattern? If the properties and objects of my business entities essentially have to be Eloquent models

Would I not always end up wrapping an eloquent model in some other layer? thus still being coupled to the active record ORM?

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan you probably need to understand why you are using an ORM from a architecture point of view. You don't have to couple your entities to an ORM. You can decouple them as I have described above. Entities ---> PersistenceGateway <---- ORM.

Comment: thanks, this is clearing things up. Can you flesh our a little bit more of an example. I think im missing something in your example.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan Uncle Bobs Clean Architecture explains how to separate out your persistence layer / ORM from your application logic and entities. Take a read of the link and google for videos on Uncle Bobs Clean Architecture for more info. I think you need to understand the concepts. If I give you an example, I still don't think it will make sense to you until you understand the theory.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan have added very basic example. If still unclear, suggest reading around clean architecture